# Json Encode in Array

Tags: php, arrays, json

Hi guys need some little help.
So I have a API that will pass a json data into another API.

The message/json must look like this:

```
[{

"MsgId": 1,
      "MsgDate": "10/18/2016 11:10:23",
      "Location": "L10129",
      "TruckNo": "AFA6790",
      "TruckerNo": "T1694",
      "DriverName": "FRANKLIN PALOR GARCIA",
      "MobileNo": "1234567890",

      "Details": [{
        "ReferenceNo": "DUMMY_REF1",
        "Origin": "Sucat",
        "Destination": "AIMS-GEN Trias Cavite City",
        "Consignee": "Juan Dela Cruz",
        "ReferenceNo2": "DUMMY_REF2"
      },{
        "ReferenceNo": "DUMMY_REF3",
        "Origin": "Sucat",
        "Destination": "AIMS-GEN Trias Cavite City",
        "Consignee": "Juan Tamad",
        "ReferenceNo2": "DUMMY_REF4"
      }]
    }]
```

However, I can't do it.It returns a internal server error.
Here is my sample code for the json:

```
$array[]=array(
                "MsgID"=>"1",
                "MsgDate"=>"10/18/2016 11:10:23",
                "Location"=>"L10129",
                "TruckNo"=>"AFA6790",

                "Details":[array(
                    "ReferenceNo"=>"DUMMY_REF1"
                )]
);

 echo json_encode($array);
```

Can someone help me on this problem?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$array[]=array(
                "MsgID"=>"1",
                "MsgDate"=>"10/18/2016 11:10:23",
                "Location"=>"L10129",
                "TruckNo"=>"AFA6790",

                "Details"=>array(array(
                    "ReferenceNo"=>"DUMMY_REF1"
                ))
);

 echo json_encode($array);
```

and the output is

```
[{"MsgID":"1","MsgDate":"10\/18\/2016 11:10:23","Location":"L10129","TruckNo":"AFA6790","Details":[{"ReferenceNo":"DUMMY_REF1"}]}]
```

Comment: Hi,i tried your answer but it doesn't work.Still i get error 500

Comment: I've eidt my code, and you can run the code on the online php, the code works.

Comment: Yes,it works!do you think it is possible on output that details section will enter into next line?